# Ping from .NET service fails after update to .NET 7

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, networking, amazon-ecs

I recently updated a .NET 6 application running in AWS ECS to .NET 7. The application is simply making a ping to an IP address. Here's the code:

```cs
using Core.Services.Common.Interfaces.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks;
using System;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Company.Redacted.Session.Core.Configuration;

namespace Company.Redacted.Session.API.v1.HealthChecks
{
    public class RedactedAvailabilityHealthCheck : IHealthCheck
    {
        #region fields

        private readonly RedactedConfiguration _redactedConfiguration;
        private readonly ILogger<RedactedAvailabilityHealthCheck> _logger;

        private static readonly int _timeout = 3000;

        #endregion

        #region ctor
        public RedactedAvailabilityHealthCheck(RedactedConfiguration redactedConfiguration, ILogger<RedactedAvailabilityHealthCheck> logger)
        {
            _redactedConfiguration = redactedConfiguration ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(redactedConfiguration));
            _logger = logger ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(logger));
        }

        #endregion

        public async Task<HealthCheckResult> CheckHealthAsync(HealthCheckContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
        {
            Ping ping = new Ping();
            PingReply reply;
            try
            {
                reply = await ping.SendPingAsync("IpAddress", _timeout, Array.Empty<byte>());
            }
            catch (PingException pingException)
            {
                _logger.LogException(pingException, "Exception occured");
                if (pingException.InnerException != null)
                {
                    _logger.LogException(pingException.InnerException, "Inner exception");
                    _logger.Error(pingException.InnerException.Message);
                }
                return Response.Failed();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                _logger.LogException(e, "Exception occured");
                return Response.Failed();
            }
            finally
            {
                ping.Dispose();
                _logger.Information("Ping disposed");
            }

            _logger.Information("Ping to {address} Status: {status}. Time: {time}ms",
                _redactedConfiguration.ServicePingAddress, reply.Status, reply.RoundtripTime);
            return reply.Status == IPStatus.Success ? HealthCheckResult.Healthy() : HealthCheckResult.Unhealthy();
        }
    }
}
```

It works a couple of times and then SendPingAsync() always throws the following exception :

```
  "exceptions": [
{
  "ClassName": "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException",
  "Depth": 0,
  "HResult": -2147467259,
  "HelpURL": null,
  "Message": "Socket not connected",
  "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
  "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
  "Source": "System.Net.Sockets",
  "StackTraceString": "   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError error, Boolean disconnectOnFailure, String callerName)\n   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.get_RemoteEndPoint()\n   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)\n   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)\n   at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.GetRawSocket(SocketConfig socketConfig)\n   at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.SendIcmpEchoRequestOverRawSocketAsync(IPAddress address, Byte[] buffer, Int32 timeout, PingOptions options)\n   at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.SendPingAsyncCore(IPAddress address, Byte[] buffer, Int32 timeout, PingOptions options)\n   at System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping.SendPingAsyncInternal(IPAddress address, Int32 timeout, Byte[] buffer, PingOptions options)"
}
```

],

This code works when I try to downgrade to .NET 6.

Edit 15:20 2022-12-19: Here's the task definition.

```json
{
    "ipcMode": null,
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::redacted:role/stage-redacted-execution-role",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "dnsSearchDomains": null,
            "environmentFiles": null,
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awsfirelens",
                "secretOptions": null,
                "options": {
                    "RemoveKeys": "container_id,ecs_task_arn",
                    "LineFormat": "key_value",
                    "Labels": "{job=\"firelens\"}",
                    "LabelKeys": "container_name,ecs_task_definition,source,ecs_cluster",
                    "Name": "grafana-loki"
                }
            },
            "entryPoint": null,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "hostPort": 80,
                    "protocol": "tcp",
                    "containerPort": 80
                }
            ],
            "command": null,
            "linuxParameters": null,
            "cpu": 256,
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT",
                    "value": "Staging"
                },
                {
                    "name": "AWS__Region",
                    "value": "eu-west-1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "ServiceName",
                    "value": "redacted"
                }
            ],
            "resourceRequirements": null,
            "ulimits": null,
            "dnsServers": null,
            "mountPoints": [],
            "workingDirectory": null,
            "secrets": [],
            "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
            "memory": 512,
            "memoryReservation": null,
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "stopTimeout": null,
            "image": "redacted",
            "startTimeout": null,
            "firelensConfiguration": null,
            "dependsOn": null,
            "disableNetworking": null,
            "interactive": null,
            "healthCheck": null,
            "essential": true,
            "links": null,
            "hostname": null,
            "extraHosts": null,
            "pseudoTerminal": null,
            "user": null,
            "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
            "dockerLabels": null,
            "systemControls": null,
            "privileged": null,
            "name": "redacted"
        },
        {
            "dnsSearchDomains": null,
            "environmentFiles": null,
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "secretOptions": null,
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/redacted-logs-configfetcher",
                    "awslogs-region": "eu-west-1",
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "stage-cluster"
                }
            },
            "entryPoint": null,
            "portMappings": [],
            "command": null,
            "linuxParameters": null,
            "cpu": 8,
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "BUCKET",
                    "value": "stage-fluentbit-config"
                },
                {
                    "name": "BUCKET_KEY",
                    "value": "fluent-bit.conf,parsers.conf"
                },
                {
                    "name": "REGION",
                    "value": "eu-west-1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "TARGET_DIR",
                    "value": "/etc/configfetcher"
                }
            ],
            "resourceRequirements": null,
            "ulimits": null,
            "dnsServers": null,
            "mountPoints": [
                {
                    "readOnly": null,
                    "containerPath": "/etc/configfetcher",
                    "sourceVolume": "config"
                }
            ],
            "workingDirectory": null,
            "secrets": [],
            "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
            "memory": 16,
            "memoryReservation": null,
            "volumesFrom": [],
            "stopTimeout": null,
            "image": "00000.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/shared/configfetcher:1.1.0",
            "startTimeout": null,
            "firelensConfiguration": null,
            "dependsOn": null,
            "disableNetworking": null,
            "interactive": null,
            "healthCheck": null,
            "essential": true,
            "links": null,
            "hostname": null,
            "extraHosts": null,
            "pseudoTerminal": null,
            "user": null,
            "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
            "dockerLabels": null,
            "systemControls": null,
            "privileged": null,
            "name": "redacted-logs-configfetcher"
        },
        {
            "dnsSearchDomains": null,
            "environmentFiles": null,
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "secretOptions": null,
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "/ecs/redacted-logrouter",
                    "awslogs-region": "eu-west-1",
                    "awslogs-create-group": "true",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "stage-cluster"
                }
            },
            "entryPoint": null,
            "portMappings": [],
            "command": [
                "/fluent-bit/bin/fluent-bit",
                "-e",
                "/fluent-bit/bin/out_grafana_loki.so",
                "-c",
                "/etc/configfetcher/fluent-bit.conf"
            ],
            "linuxParameters": null,
            "cpu": 32,
            "environment": [
                {
                    "name": "LABELS",
                    "value": "{job=\"redacted\"}"
                },
                {
                    "name": "PARSERS_FILE",
                    "value": "/etc/configfetcher/parsers.conf"
                }
            ],
            "resourceRequirements": null,
            "ulimits": null,
            "dnsServers": null,
            "mountPoints": [],
            "workingDirectory": null,
            "secrets": [
                {
                    "valueFrom": "//stage/integration/endpoint/loki",
                    "name": "LOKI_URL"
                }
            ],
            "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
            "memory": null,
            "memoryReservation": null,
            "volumesFrom": [
                {
                    "sourceContainer": "redacted-logs-configfetcher",
                    "readOnly": null
                }
            ],
            "stopTimeout": null,
            "image": "0000.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/shared/fluent-bit-plugin-loki:2.3.0-amd64",
            "startTimeout": null,
            "firelensConfiguration": {
                "type": "fluentbit",
                "options": {
                    "enable-ecs-log-metadata": "true"
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "containerName": "redacted-logs-configfetcher",
                    "condition": "START"
                }
            ],
            "disableNetworking": null,
            "interactive": null,
            "healthCheck": null,
            "essential": true,
            "links": null,
            "hostname": null,
            "extraHosts": null,
            "pseudoTerminal": null,
            "user": "0",
            "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
            "dockerLabels": null,
            "systemControls": null,
            "privileged": null,
            "name": "redacted-logrouter"
        }
    ],
    "placementConstraints": [],
    "memory": "1024",
    "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::redacted:role/stage-redacted-task-role",
    "compatibilities": [
        "EC2",
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:redacted:task-definition/redacted:302",
    "family": "redacted",
    "requiresAttributes": [
        {
            "targetId": null,
            "targetType": null,
            "value": null,
            "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
        },
        {
            "targetId": null,
            "targetType": null,
            "value": null,
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
        },
        {
            "targetId": null,
            "targetType": null,
            "value": null,
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.17"
        },
        {
            "targetId": null,
            "targetType": null,
            "value": null,
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awsfirelens"
        },
        {
            "targetId": null,
            "targetType": null,
            "value": null,
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.task-iam-role"
        },
        {
            "targetId": null,
            "targetType": null,
            "value": null,
            "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-ecr-pull"
        },
        {
            "targetId": null,
            "targetType": null,
            "value": null,
            "name": "ecs.capability.secrets.ssm.environment-variables"
        },
        {
            "targetId": null,
            "targetType": null,
            "value": null,
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
        },
        {
            "targetId": null,
            "targetType": null,
            "value": null,
            "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
        },
        {
            "targetId": null,
            "targetType": null,
            "value": null,
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.29"
        },
        {
            "targetId": null,
            "targetType": null,
            "value": null,
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
        },
        {
            "targetId": null,
            "targetType": null,
            "value": null,
            "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
        },
        {
            "targetId": null,
            "targetType": null,
            "value": null,
            "name": "ecs.capability.firelens.fluentbit"
        },
        {
            "targetId": null,
            "targetType": null,
            "value": null,
            "name": "ecs.capability.container-ordering"
        }
    ],
    "pidMode": null,
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "FARGATE"
    ],
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "runtimePlatform": null,
    "cpu": "512",
    "revision": 302,
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "inferenceAccelerators": null,
    "proxyConfiguration": null,
    "volumes": [
        {
            "fsxWindowsFileServerVolumeConfiguration": null,
            "efsVolumeConfiguration": null,
            "name": "config",
            "host": {
                "sourcePath": null
            },
            "dockerVolumeConfiguration": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Does it then start working? Or does it then always fail? Is there a specific time duration pattern? What's your ECS task config? Can you replicate this locally?

Comment: Do the Docker and ECS logs indicate anything? `sudo cat /var/log/ecs/ecs-agent.log.YYYY-MM-DD-**` and `sudo cat /var/log/docker` should get some useful data.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary it works a couple of times then it completely stops working. The program sends a ping every 30 seconds. My ECS task config hasn't changed, only the .NET version in my docker image. Unfortunately can't try locally because the IP address is only available from my AWS instance. The docker logs don't show anything

Comment: Can you please add your task definition and details about which image you're using to your post? Can you please also solidify your code example e.g. I can see `_timeout` being used but I can't see it being defined anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @ErmiyaEskandary. I'm a coworker of AnthonyG. The _timeout is 3000. I edited the question, but it won't show up immediately. Everything in the .cs file should now be visible, and task definition should be present. However, I had to redact some things. Such as account id, the service name, and environment/secrets. It should hopefully be visible soon

Comment: Thanks! @AntonBlomström how are you upgrading and downgrading? is that the only change? are there any other code changes you're making? how is your `RedactedAvailabilityHealthCheck` registered? there's a lot at play here potentially; and goes without saying, are you sure the endpoint remains up?

Comment: And is that the full exception including the inner exception? It doesn't seem to be a full stack trace. Are there any patterns i.e. error is triggered after 45 minutes or always triggered at 4pm UTC or etc. ?

Comment: We're upgrading/downgrading by changing the image version in the dockerfile, that's the only change. No change to the code or task definition. RedactedAvailabilityHeathCheck is registered in the startup file as healthcheck : services.AddHealthChecks().AddCheck<RedactedAvailabilityHealthCheck>().
The healtheck is done every 30 seconds. The first healthcheck always works but then they always fail. The exception in this post is the inner the exception, the main exception is of type PingException